# New Android project in Eclipse: Theme select drop down menu is hidden

Tags: android, eclipse

I face this problem for about 2 months. When I create a new android project the theme select drop down menu is hidden and in create activity menu (in the wizard) I can not create a blank activity (only full screen activity). What should I do?

Comment: Which versions of Eclipse and Android plugin are you using? Also, what platform are you running that in?

Comment: Windows. ADT Version 22.0.0